# Node.js. Express - using mysql and pooled connections unexpected behaviour with next(error)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

```
This is my route:

router.get('/:slug/:postId/:key', function(req, res, next) {
   
    const returnData = (data, error) =>
    {
        
        if (error)
        {
            next(error);
        }
        else
        {
            res.type('application/json');//TODO
            res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        
    }

    let params = req.params;
    let json = data.getJson(params, returnData, next);
   
});
```

And this is  the function data.getJson which actually gets the data and returns it:

```
const getJson = (params, callback, next) =>
{


    const { slug, postId, key } = params;
   
    let sql = "SELECT * from `table` WHERE `column` = " + Number(postId); 

         pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
         

            if (err) 
            {
                next(err);
                return; 
            }
        

            connection.query({
                sql: sql,
                timeout: 40000, // 40s
                }, function (err, result, fields) {
                    
                    if (err) 
                    {
                        callback(undefined, err);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            //this does some processing on the json from the db
                            let jsonObj = formatJson(params, result[0].column);
                            callback(jsonObj, undefined);
                        }
                        catch (error)
                        {
                            callback(undefined, error);
                        }
                    }
                    connection.release();
             
            });
        });

}
```

My custom error handler:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

    if (req.xhr) 
    {
        console.log("JSON ERROR", err);
        res.type('application/json');
        res.status(500).send({ 
            error: true,
            
        });
    }
    
});
```

My question concerns the return statement after the next(error) just after pool.getConnection. If I use this everything works as expected. E.g. if I force a connection error by using a non-existent database name then my error handler is called and works. But if I do not put return here it is not and I get the following returned: "@����k/���gesponse received from application".

From the Express documentation:

If you pass anything to the next() function (except the string 'route'), Express regards the current request as being an error and will skip any remaining non-error handling routing and middleware functions.

So, in this case, it looks like it is not skipping straight to my custom error handler.

In general I do not have to put return; after next(error) - for example in the callback returnData.

I guess the fact that it happens inside the database connection call is the reason - but I do not understand why. My question is: why do I need to put return; after next(error) in the connection callback?

Thank you

Comment: I don't want to put it as the answer to my own question, because I am not sure, but looking at other SO questions the point may be that i need the return to exit the current function and prevent it trying the query on the non-existent database?

Comment: yes, it is there to exit the function before using the faulty connection. calling `next(err)` is an express thing to pass the request along to next handlers. that make sense to be the last thing executing in a callback.